# Solving a recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion

Let $\{c_t\}_{t = 1}^k$ be a (non-monotone) sequence of real numbers such that $c_t \in (0, 1]$ for all $t = 1, \dots, k$. Consider the recursive sequence
$$ \left \{
\begin{array}{ll}
x_1 & = c_1 & \\
x_{t + 1} & = c_{k + 1} \left (1 - \alpha \sum_{j = 1}^t x_{j} \right ) & \mbox{for all } 1 \leq t < k\\
\end{array}
\right . $$
with $\alpha > 0$ a constant indipendent of $t$. Find a closed-form formula for the sequence $\{x_t\}_{t = 1}^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As

$$
\frac{x_{k+1}}{c_{k+1}} = 1-\alpha\sum_{j=1}^{j=k}x_j
$$

calling $y_k = \frac{x_k}{c_k}$ we have

$$
y_{k+1}-y_k = -\alpha x_k = -\alpha c_k y_k
$$

so we have

$$
y_{k+1}+(\alpha c_k - 1)y_k = 0
$$

this is a recurrence linear equation with solution

$$
y_k = C_0 \prod_{j=1}^{j=k-1}(1-\alpha c_j)
$$

and finally

$$
x_k = C_0 c_k\prod_{j=1}^{j=k-1}(1-\alpha c_j)
$$

but as $x_{1} = c_1$ follows $C_0 = 1$

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$
\frac{x_{t+1}}{c_{t+1}}-\frac{x_{t}}{c_{t}}=-\alpha x_t
$$
Can you take it from here?